# Loading a prior map with gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to load a previously saved map (pgm/yaml) into gmapping, such that the map is initially populated with the robot situated at a defined starting pose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9448/loading-a-prior-map-with-gmapping/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it's not.  The occupancy grid representation of the map (for example, the pgm bitmap) doesn't contain enough state to resume mapping.  Internally, gmapping is estimating a distribution over maps and robot trajectories, using a particle filter.  To resume mapping, you'd have to save all of that internal state.  In principle, it's possible to do that, but it's not currently implemented, and I would guess it would take quite a bit of work.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2011-12-29**:
the new version of Karto will do this for you; they provide a ROS package interface, but it ain't free... (except for trial license)

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-03-16**:
For long-term mapping, including pause-and-resume abilities, I'd go for a constraint-graph SLAM algorithm, instead of a particle filter algorithm.  I don't know whether it's implemented yet, but the [graph_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/graph_mapping) stack should eventually be able to do this.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-16**:
Ok, I thought that might be the case.  It would be nice to have a life-long learning approach to building maps, so that any changes in the environment can be accommodated.  Saving the particle filter state might be something I could work on.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-07**:
Hi, according to the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack,
it is possible to load a static map into rviz. But I am also unable to load the static map? Anyone solve this issue?

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-09-15**:
@RB rviz is used to display the static map, not load it.  To load it, check out map_server.  Also, your question is almost completely unrelated to this question, so you should have posted this as a different question.

**Comment by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on 2016-03-01**:
Is it possible that we have a solution by getting the current location to resume gmapping?
I suggest comparing the current view for the sight sensors to the old map & see where is this current robot.
Any luck on this? In fact I m working on somthing similar, anyone with solutions to this solution?

**Comment by [Dino](https://answers.ros.org/users/28388/dino/) on 2016-10-30**:
I am interested in this with a few handy (I believe) constraints. Imagine a robot that maps, then docks to recharge. The dock is at the same location as the start of previous mapping. How to restart from known origin and orientation, then?